# dimension too large problem by plotting 1/cos^2 using tizk/pgf

Tags: tikz-pgf

my code looks as follow:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-4.3,xmax=7.8,ymin=-4.5,ymax=4.5,
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$}
    ]

  \addplot[blue,samples=200] {1/cos(deg(x))^2}node[right]{$y=1/\cos^2(x)$};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: The cosine has zeros in the domain you choose. You could just plot `min(1/cos(deg(x))^2,5)` instead since your `ymax` is smaller than `5`.

Comment: Please consider posting a full [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) next time. It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cosine has zeros in the domain you choose. Therefore your function has poles. You could just plot `min(1/cos(deg(x))^2,5)` instead since your `ymax` is smaller than `5`, so it does not really matter what value you plot in these dangerous regimes: as long as they are larger than `ymax` they will not be plotted anyway. And your `node` seems to get cut away, but I would like to argue that using a legend here will be more appropriate.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle, xmin=-4.3,xmax=7.8,ymin=-4.5,ymax=4.5,
xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$},
legend pos=south east,]
\addplot[blue,samples=200] {min(1/cos(deg(x))^2,5)}; 
\addlegendentry{$y=1/\cos^2(x)$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]